# Странная запятая в ССП

Tags: ссп

> Там месяц глядел под мою родную кровлю, и там впервые узнал и полюбил
> я его кроткое и бледное лицо...

Не понимаю, откуда взялась запятая. Ведь здесь есть общее местоименное наречие у частей СП, пусть даже оно и повторяется, но это одно и то же слово. В правилах нет оговорки на этот счет.

Comment: Какое **там** общее? Почему не второе?

Comment: а почему оно должно быть общим, если это всего лишь повтор?

Comment: Я вопрос задал... и получил вопрос. Весело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Заданный текст:**

*Давно не видел я такой ночи! И вот мысли мои опять возвратились к далёким, почти забытым осенним ночам, которые видел я когда-то в детстве среди холмистой и скудной степи средней России. **Там** месяц глядел под мою родную кровлю, **и там** впервые узнал и полюбил я его кроткое и бледное лицо.*

Повторение местоимения "там" **необходимо** в этом тексте (его никак не перестроишь).  Можно записать так:

***В средней полосе  России** / месяц глядел под мою родную кровлю, **и там** впервые узнал и полюбил я его кроткое и бледное лицо.*

**Пояснение**

Это ***СПП,*** в каждом предложении свое **грамматическое обстоятельство**, и неважно, повторяется ли оно или нет.

А важно вот что: второе предложение **распространяет** первое, а объединить общим обстоятельством можно **только однородные по смыслу**  предложения, например: ***В лунном свете** все изменилось и лицо его выглядело бледным.* Здесь события отнесены **к одному моменту времени**, а общее обстоятельство связывает их.

Или так: ***В России** мы встретились и он стал моим лучшим другом.*  Здесь общее **место** действия.

**[ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (стр. 221)](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)**

Различаются ССП **однородного и неоднородного** состава. Однородность состава проявляется **в одинаковом отношении предикативных частей к общему члену** — реальному или подразумеваемому, в одинаковом отношении к предыдущему тексту или в одинаковом отношении говорящего к перечисляемым событиям:

**Признаки ССП однородного состава:**

1. открытая структура: такие ССП могут включать больше двух предикативных частей, и ряд предикативных частей может быть продолжен (является открытым);
2. предикативные части **равноправны в смысловом и грамматическом отношении**;
3. предикативные части могут иметь общий второстепенный
   член; общую придаточную часть; однородные придаточные имеют общую главную часть;
4. основные средства связи — союзы и, да, и...и, ни... ни; а; то...то, не то...не то, или...или;
5. одинаковая оформленность каждой предикативной части:
   **общий модальный план, одинаковый функциональный тип** (т.е. предикативные части не могут быть разными по цели высказывания, например вопросительной и невопросительной);
6. **перечислительная** интонация.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая стоит правильно:

*Там месяц глядел под мою родную кровлю, и там впервые узнал и полюбил я его кроткое и бледное лицо...*

Если убрать одно из одинаковых наречий, то, если оно будет общим, запятая уже нужна не будет:

*Месяц глядел под мою родную кровлю и **там** впервые узнал и полюбил я его кроткое и бледное лицо...*

***Там** месяц глядел под мою родную кровлю и впервые узнал и полюбил я его кроткое и бледное лицо...*

Общее наречие — запятая не нужна.

Но в этом предложении одно и то же наречие есть и там и там, то есть, если будет одно наречие, оно будет общим; но если это наречие повторить в другой части, то где возьмëтся общий член?

Если в примере с одним обстоятельством к нему были подключены два предложения, то, если их раздвоить, каждое предложение будет подключено к своему члену предложения — следовательно, общего члена нет — для каждого свой.